# Parcelable how to use the 'KEY' value when receiving all the information?

Tags: android, arraylist, parcelable

I'm making an Android application and I would like to send an `ArrayList` to the next `Activity`, but I don't know how to do this with `Parcelable`.

For example: I got an `int` named as `ID` and a `String` named as `Names`. I use JSON for getting all informations from PHP and MySQL.

In the for-loop I add all those `Names` and `ID` to a class. But then I don't know how to write all these `Names` and `ID` into a `bundle.putParcelableArrayList(KEY, ArrayList...);`, because I don't know how to do this with the `KEY` value. Do I need to give the `KEY` value numbers or is there automatically one `KEY`?

```
class alleDeelnemers implements Parcelable {

    int id;
    String name;

    /* GETTER AND SETTER */

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(id);
        dest.writeString(volgnummer);
    }

    public alleDeelnemers(Parcel in) {
        volgnummer = in.readString();
        id = in.readInt();
    }

    // Creator
    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public alleDeelnemers createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new alleDeelnemers(in);
        }

        public alleDeelnemers[] newArray(int size) {
            return new alleDeelnemers[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Receiving data:

```
ArrayList<alleDeelnemers> deelnemers = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0; i < jArrayDeelnemer.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject json_data = jArrayDeelnemer.getJSONObject(i);

    //class alleDeelnemers
    deelnemer = new alleDeelnemers();

    //ID
    int ID = json_data.getInt("ID");
    deelnemer.setId(ID);
    //alle deelnemers
    String name = json_data.getString("name ");  
    deelnemer.setName(name );

    //toevoegen in de class
    deelnemers.add(deelnemer);
}
```

error this line: `deelnemer = new alleDeelnemers();` need to build a constructor.

Comment: Please post the code of whatever you were trying.

Comment: The key should be unique, this is a map that link a key and a value. If you can't generate unique key (`ID` value), you could store does into a Parcelable container

Comment: So I can store an ArrayList in a Parcelable container?

Comment: An ArrayList is Parcelable (if the Items are). SO you can put a list into a Bundle (if this is what you asked) with [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String))

Comment: Yes that's what I asked, thanks man!

Comment: @sanderlemmen see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40888621/3629732)

Comment: Getter and Setter class should be implement serializable

Comment: @sanderlemmen You are updating your question adding more problems. This is not how that works, you can't change the scope of the question...be careful...

Comment: Thanks AxelH for changing your vote and helping me with improving my question for in the future. But he asked me for updating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is any name you would use to reference your `ArrayList`. Further in the started activity, you will use this key to retrieve the `ArrayList`. For example, in the initial activity, do

```
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("MY_ARRAY_LIST", deelnemers);
```

and then in the started activity, to retrieve it later

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<alleDeelnemers> list = b.getParcelableArrayList("MY_ARRAY_LIST");
```

Note that the KEY used here is "MY_ARRAY_LIST". It is a better practice to use xml string constants or an interface for storing constant KEYS.

Comment: But first I need to make my class: "alleDeelnemers" Parcelable, right?

Comment: Correct, make it implement `Parcelable` or `Serializable`. `Parcelable` is the preferred way to do it in Android.

Comment: I'm going to write some code and over 10 minutes I will change my code of what I writed.

Comment: I forget the key I see.. How do I set a key?

Comment: Read my answer again, the key can be any string, you just need to use the same string (key) again when you want to retrieve the ArrayList

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't thinking straight. I already have an example of the key. But I got an erroy when I try to create a new class in the for loop.

Comment: Edit your question and put the stack trace there

Comment: Need to create a constructor and then I got automatically a new 'public alleDeelnemers(){}' in the class.

Answer (score 0):

1.First create your alleDeelnemers class as Parcelable using [plug-in](http://corochann.com/fast-easy-parcelable-implementation-with-android-studio-parcelable-plugin-641.html)

2 Sender Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("mData", myArrayList);
```

3 Receiver Activity

```
myArrayList = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("mData")
```

Comment: I finally found an answer.